# How to add maple and brown sugar to cream of wheat

Tags: flavor

I'm a total novice to good cooking. I was wondering how to add my own maple and brown sugar to regular cream of wheat. I live in Canada and cannot get the full box of maple and brown sugar c.o.w. and have to buy the variety box where you  get packets and only 2 are maple and brown sugar! So I thought why not make my own. And now for the questions. How much maple and brown sugar per serving? Do I add during cooking or after? Do I use maple extract, maple flavoring, or maple syrup? Should I just drive to the states and buy a box? Ha. Thanx.

Comment: If you live in Canada, surely you can't be serious about using anything other than pure maple syrup.

Comment: @ElmerCat I had that thought too :)

Comment: Well of course you can't beat pure maple syrup. My dilemma is could I cook with it, or when cooking should it be with maple flavoring or extract.

Comment: The main reason to use extract/flavor is when you want to add the flavor without having to add much sugar or liquid. Not really an issue with cream of wheat probably.

Comment: Thanx. So does that mean extract/flavoring isn't really sweet as much as it is a flavor? I definitely have a sweet tooth, so were I to add extract or flavoring I would have to add some extra brown sugar? I reckon the easiest way is the best way. Make the cream of wheat and then add on the maple syrup and brown sugar on top. Thanks all.

Comment: @Bill Yep, that's the way to do it. Just another quick note, the 2.5 minute variety is much better than the instant. That and real brown sugar and maple syrup will make you forget all about the flavored instant packets.

Comment: Chopped toasted pecans are also a great addition. In the states we can get them at Trader Joe's and elsewhere.  Get the unsalted ones.  Enjoy!

Comment: @Bill I'd suggest asking posting separate questions if you want to know more; that way people have space to write full answers and it'll be easier for future readers to find too.

Answer (score 4):

Just sprinkle the brown sugar and drizzle maple syrup on the cooked cereal. It's better that way than the flavored packets anyway. Start with a little of each and add more until it is as flavored as you want it. No need to mix it in, that it is a bit separate from the cereal is nice. BTW, peanut butter is good that way too, in addition to one or both of the other ingredients you mention.

Comment: Thanx. I guess sometimes the easiest way is the safest. At least for me, haha. Thanks again.

Comment: Plus, if you're feeding a crowd, it allows them to flavor it however they prefer rather than following your taste for sweetness.